# Task process ending before finishing all the work

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I've been having trouble running multiple tasks with heavy operations.
It seems as if the task processes is killed before all the operations are complete.

The code here is an example code I used to replicate the issue. If I add something like Debug.Write(), the added wait for writing fixes the issue. The issue is gone if I test on a smaller sample size too. The reason there is a class in the example below is to create complexity for the test.
The real case where I encountered the issue first is too complicated to explain for a post here.

```
public static class StaticRandom
{
    static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> random =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed)));

    public static int Next()
    {
        return random.Value.Next();
    }

    public static int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        return random.Value.Next(maxValue);
    }

    public static double NextDouble()
    {
        return random.Value.NextDouble();
    }
}

// this is the test function I run to recreate the problem:
static void tasktest()
{
    var testlist = new List<ExampleClass>();
    for (var index = 0; index < 10000; ++index)
    {
        var newClass = new ExampleClass();
        newClass.Populate(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToList());
        testlist.Add(newClass);
    }
    var anotherClassList = new List<ExampleClass>();
    var threadNumber = 5;

    if (threadNumber > testlist.Count)
    {
        threadNumber = testlist.Count;
    }

    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

    int stuffPerThread = testlist.Count / threadNumber;
    var stuffCounter = 0;
    for (var count = 1; count <= threadNumber; ++count)
    {
        var toSkip = stuffCounter;
        var threadWorkLoad = stuffPerThread;
        var currentIndex = count;

        // these ifs make sure all the indexes are covered
        if (stuffCounter + threadWorkLoad > testlist.Count)
        {
            threadWorkLoad = testlist.Count - stuffCounter;
        }
        else if (count == threadNumber && stuffCounter + threadWorkLoad < testlist.Count)
        {
            threadWorkLoad = testlist.Count - stuffCounter;
        }

        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskfunc(testlist, anotherClassList, toSkip, threadWorkLoad),
            cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default));
        stuffCounter += stuffPerThread;
    }

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}

public class ExampleClass
{
    public ExampleClassInner[] Inners { get; set; }

    public ExampleClass()
    {
        Inners = new ExampleClassInner[5];
        for (var index = 0; index < Inners.Length; ++index)
        {
            Inners[index] = new ExampleClassInner();
        }
    }

    public void Populate(List<int> intlist) {/*adds random ints to the inner class*/}


    public ExampleClass(ExampleClass copyFrom)
    {
        Inners = new ExampleClassInner[5];
        for (var index = 0; index < Inners.Length; ++index)
        {
            Inners[index] = new ExampleClassInner(copyFrom.Inners[index]);
        }
    }

    public class ExampleClassInner
    {
        public bool SomeBool { get; set; } = false;
        public int SomeInt { get; set; } = -1;

        public ExampleClassInner()
        {
        }

        public ExampleClassInner(ExampleClassInner copyFrom)
        {
            SomeBool = copyFrom.SomeBool;
            SomeInt = copyFrom.SomeInt;
        }
    }
}

static int expensivefunc(int theint)
{ 
/*a lot of pointless arithmetic and loops done only on primitives and with primitives, 
just to increase the complexity*/
    theint *= theint + 1;
    var anotherlist = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToList();
    for (var index = 0; index < anotherlist.Count; ++index)
    {
        theint += index;
        if (theint % 5 == 0)
        {
            theint *= index / 2;
        }
    }
    var yetanotherlist = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000).ToList();
    for (var index = 0; index < yetanotherlist.Count; ++index)
    {
        theint += index;
        if (theint % 7 == 0)
        {
            theint -= index / 3;
        }
    }
    while (theint > 8)
    {
        theint /= 2;
    }

    return theint;
}

// this function is intentionally creating a lot of objects, to simulate complexity
static void taskfunc(List<ExampleClass> intlist, List<ExampleClass> anotherClassList, int skip, int take)
{
    if (take == 0)
    {
        take = intlist.Count;
    }
    var partial = intlist.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
    for (var index = 0; index < partial.Count; ++index)
    {
        var testint = expensivefunc(index);
        var newClass = new ExampleClass(partial[index]);
        newDna.Inners[StaticRandom.Next(5)].SomeInt = testint;
        anotherClassList.Add(new ExampleClass(newClass));
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the list `anotherClassList` will be the same size as `testlist` and this happens when the lists are smaller or the complexity of the task operations is smaller. However, when I increase the volume of operations, the `anotherClassList` has a few indexes missing and sometimes some of the indexes in the list are null objects.

Example result:

[image]

Why does this happen, I have `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: Its not about `Task.WaitAll`, you have exception at the following line, `Inners[index] = new ExampleClassInner(copyFrom.Inners[index]);`, which making program exit, `copyFrom` doesn't have `Inners` array instantiated

Comment: I would be preferable to create simple reproduction code to explain the issue, there's no issue with `Task.WaitAll`, that would work as expected

Comment: My spidey senses tell me you have too many *degrees of freedom* you don't have under control, and also that this should be done a loooot differently. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I did not include everything in the code, I have edited the code to include it all, my bad. The constructor of the ExampleClass creates the Inners, there is no exception.
I've included the `StaticRandom` class and the `expensivefunc` code too now

Comment: @TheGeneral I did not include all of the code previously, now I did, my bad. You can try to compile it now.

The original issue is inside a genetic algorithm that creates the next generation. It is involved in a machine learning project.
I am trying to speed up the generation by splitting it into seperate threads.

Comment: So your problem is `anotherClassList` should be the same length as `testList` ?

Comment: @TheGeneral , basically yes. The tasks I create should iterate through all of `testList`, then on each iteration do some heavy operations (which in the genetic algorithm is crossover(breeding) and mutation operations) and take the result of the operations and add it in the new list, which in this case is `anotherClassList`. I know they can iterate because it works when the operations are simpler or the lists smaller. So the problem must be somewhere else and I suspect that the task processes are killed before all the operations are done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After TheGeneral enlightened me that Lists are not thread safe, I changed the List to which I was adding in a thread, to an Array type and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is it's just not thread-safe; you just can't add to a `list<T>` in a multi-threaded environment and expect it to play nice.

One way is to use `lock` or a [thread safe collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/), but I feel this all should be refactored (my OCD is going off all over the place).

```
private static object _sync = new object();

...

private static void TaskFunc(List<ExampleClass> intlist, List<ExampleClass> anotherClassList, int skip, int take)
{

   ...

   var partial = intlist.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

   ...

   // note that locking here will likely drastically decrease any performance threading gain
   lock (_sync)
   {
      for (var index = 0; index < partial.Count; ++index)
      {
         // this is your problem, you are adding to a list from multiple threads
         anotherClassList.Add(...);
      }
   }

}
```

In short, I think you need to better thinking about the threading logic of your method, identify what you are trying to achieve, and how to make it conceptually thread safe (while keeping your performance gains).

Comment: I will try locking.

Comment: I thought only adding is thread safe. Is replacing a particular index thread safe?

Comment: @Sadem Nothing to do with a `List<T>` is thread safe. it works on an internal managed buffer (array), that buffer and its associated memory could be doing anything on any thread

Comment: This may be the problem indeed, thank you. I will look into it later and see what happens.

P.S. This is just some example code I wrote in 10 minutes to replicate the issue without the 500+ lines of the original genetic algorithm, so its a little messy

Comment: I changed it from List to Array, which fixed the issue(and it's faster than List).

Comment: `Array` is as thread safe as list, only thing here is you can cautiously divide array index between threads, thus avoid corruption, though a thread safe data structure like `ConcurrentBag<T>` or the custom thread safe list, check one that i have created [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62033/creating-a-thread-safe-list-using-a-lock-object)

Comment: Also you shall mark this one as Answer as it helped you resolve the issue